# Multiple submission in a page using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am implementing a Web-based Java app using Spring MVC.

What I am doing now is to provide a page which allow users to select from a set of radio buttons and export a set of data in CSV by clicking the "Submit" button.

However, I have encountered a situation.

After users download one CSV, whenever they want to download another one, if they click "Submit" button again, the download process will not be fired and a dialog saying "Action already submitted. Wait until the action is complete." will show up.

Here is my codes:

```
<form:form action="handle_export?user_id=${userId}" method="post">
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input id="set0" type="radio" name="exportType" value="0"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label for="set0">dataset0 Export</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input id="set1" type="radio" name="exportType" value="1"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label for="set1">dataset1  Export</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            <input type="button" class="submit button-1" value="Download" name="bottom_Download" />
    </form:form>
```

Any chance that I can fire the "Submit" button multiple times?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I doubt your issue has anything to do with Spring. Looks like some javascript that is being triggered when the button is hit the first time. Spring on it own does not enforce one-button-one-submission

Comment: Is this for a Blackboard building block by any chance? If so, it might be Bb's code intercepting the second request. I ran into the same issue and haven't figured out how to send multiple submissions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. After digging deep into the codes, I have found that the cause of the issue, which is related to a javascript function. That function somehow prevent multiple submission for the page.
@ruperto17, although I have no experience in developing Blackboard program, I heard that it is a disaster for programmer, especially the tag library. Good luck on the Blackboard implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with blackboard and I have solved doing:

-Remove "action" from FORM 
-Create a function on JS, by example: generateCSV()
-Function would be like that:

```
var userid = document.getElementById('userid');
window.open('handle_export?user_id=' + userid);
```

On handle_export, retrieve the values following:

```
String userid = request.getParameter("userid");
// ...
// generate and download file
```

This way, its opened in a new window and blackboard not show up the dialog saying "Action already submitted. Wait until the action is complete." .

I hope this helps, regards.